# synergy interprets a 'space' for a 'slash'

Tags: linux, macos, synergy

My setup is :

- Linux Server
- OSX Client

Every time I use the `space` on my Linux box keyboard (and the pointer/focus is in a window on my OSX machine), I get a `slash` '/' instead.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known defect](https://github.com/synergy/synergy/issues/2765) in Synergy. It looks like a pretty widespread problem. It's still unfixed at this time. But if you go through the comments, there are some workarounds. Some people mention that setting the Mac keyboard to british fixes it. One person mentions using [QuickSynergy](https://code.google.com/p/quicksynergy/).